# Twig `{% image %}` only includes all images in DEV and not in PROD

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I have the below code in my twig template which works just fine in development and displays all the images in the directory as I would expect:

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/images/designz/*' %}
      <img src="{{ asset_url }}" width="600" />
{% endimage %}
```

However, when I move the site to the production environment I do not get any of the images appearing. I have tried submitting the below commands in the hope of fixing it but with no luck:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assets:install
```

Comment: Compare your Assetic configuration on config_prod.yml and config_dev.yml. Are your bundles added for both environments?

Comment: I have the `assetic: filters` for both in my main `config.yml`. The only other mention in my environment-specific yml files is in `config_dev.yml` which has `assetic: user_controller: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your case in my project. And i think that `*` isn't working for an image file. In dev mode Symfony make more image tags in production mode Symfony try to merge that files to one output file and that isn't normally not working for image files because you have some meta data for example. If you have some different files in that folder for example png and jpeg you try to merge them.

This function is correct if you use filter and pipe that result to an output.

**Production:**

```
<img src="/images/925f36b.png" width="600">
```

**Dev:**

```
<img src="/app_dev.php/images/925f36b_part_1_hellgrau_1.png" width="600">
<img src="/app_dev.php/images/925f36b_part_1_xxx_2.png" width="600">
```

But finally i think with images you can use only one file.

Comment: Thank you - that sounds like it could be the problem then - although I'm not sure I follow on your code example for Production where you mention just one png file.... filtering and piping all images into one??

Comment: Symfony try to merge bot PNG files to one and that isn't working. You can check that with Firebug for example.

Comment: Twig doesn't try to merge any image automatically if you don't implement an output parameter.

Comment: @DavidVartanian i have copied that code from top. And how you can see its not correct or what do you think and i haven't used the output.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try only with one image?

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

Regarding the Symfony documentation *image* recognises only one file, not a directory.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-images